# How to animate the position of multiple divs with JQuery?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate

I have a list of `<div>` elements and would like to animate their positions. For example, I might have 4 div's inside a container as follows:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="bar" style="height: 70px"> 70 </div>
  <div class="bar" style="height: 50px"> 50 </div>
  <div class="bar" style="height: 30px"> 30 </div>
  <div class="bar" style="height: 10px"> 10 </div>
</div>
```

Now, let's say I wanted to move the div at index 1 in list

```
<div class="bar" style="height: 50px"> 50 </div>
```

To the position of the div at index 0 in the list

```
<div class="bar" style="height: 70px"> 70 </div>
```

I would call the function,

```
animateBar(1, 0)
```

The problem is that after the animation completes, the order of the divs jumps around.

I understand that the reason for the behaviour comes from the line `div2.insertBefore(div1)` but I am unsure what to put here to prevent the jumping around from happening. I have tried an assortment of `before, after, insertBefore, and insertAfter` but none of these seem to fix the problem.

What's going wrong and how can I fix it?

```js
function animateBar(fromIndex, toIndex) {
  const div1 = $(".bar").eq(fromIndex);
  const div2 = $(".bar").eq(toIndex);
  const distance = div1.offset().left - div2.offset().left;

  $.when(
    div1.animate({
        left: -distance
      },
      1000
    )
  ).done(() => {
    div1.css("left", "0px");
    div2.insertBefore(div1);
  });
}

$("button").click(function() {
  animateBar(1, 0);
  animateBar(0, 1);

  setTimeout(function() {
    animateBar(3, 2);
    animateBar(2, 3);
  }, 2000);

  setTimeout(function() {
    animateBar(2, 0);
    animateBar(0, 1);
    animateBar(1, 2);
  }, 4000);
});
```

```css
.container {
  width: 100vw;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

.bar {
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px;
  background: lightblue;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button>
  Sort
</button>
<div class="container">
  <div class="bar" style="height: 70px">
    70
  </div>
  <div class="bar" style="height: 50px">
    50
  </div>
  <div class="bar" style="height: 30px">
    30
  </div>
  <div class="bar" style="height: 10px">
    10
  </div>
</div>
```

[View on jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jksefc24/7/)